# Groovy ConfigSlurper is only partially building the structure when parsed

Tags: groovy

I am building a library for myself and using `ConfigSlurper` to parse a `config.groovy` file, and other config sources into an aggregated `ConfigObject` that I am using Micronaught compile time IOC to inject

```
    @Bean
    @Named('config')
    ConfigObject config () {

        Map envMap = [:]
        def sysProps = System.getenv()
        if (System.getProperty("env") ) {
            envMap = System.getenv().findResult { it.key?.toLowerCase().contains "env" }.collect { [(it.key?.toLowerCase().substring(0, 2)): it.value.toLowerCase()] }
        } else
            envMap.get ('env', "development")
        def env = envMap.get('env')

        def resourcePath = "src${File.separatorChar}${env =="test" ?: "main"}${File.separatorChar}resources${File.separatorChar}"
        ConfigObject config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("${resourcePath}ApplicationConfig.groovy").text /*.toURI().toURL()*/)
        config.put('systemProperties', sysProps)
        config.putAll(envMap)

        config.put('projectPath', System.getProperty("user.dir"))
        config.put('resourcesPath', resourcePath.toString())

        File resourceDirectory = new File ("${System.getProperty("user.dir")}$File.separatorChar$resourcePath")
        FilenameFilter filter = {file, name -> name.matches(~/^.*properties$/) }
        List propsFiles = resourceDirectory.listFiles (filter)

        filter = {file, name -> name.matches(~/^.*yaml$/) }
        List yamlFiles = resourceDirectory.listFiles (filter)

        propsFiles.each {file ->
            Properties prop = new Properties()
            prop.load(new FileInputStream (file) )
            Map propsMap = [:]
            for (key in prop.stringPropertyNames()) {
                propsMap.put(key, prop.getProperty(key))
            }
            config.putAll(propsMap)
        }

        yamlFiles.each {file ->
            def yamlConfig = new YamlSlurper().parseText(file.text)
            config.putAll(yamlConfig)
        }

        config
    }
```

the `resources/applicationConfig.groovy` file looks like this

```
    framework {
        environments {
            development {
                server = "local" // choice of {local|clustered}
                vertxOptions {
    
                }
    
            }
            test {
                server = "local" // choice of {local|clustered}
                vertxOptions {
    
                }
    
            }
            production {
                server = "clustered" // choice of {local|clustered}
                vertxOptions {
    
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

The code parses the groovy file but when I look at what in the `configObject`, its created the tope level framework map entry - but the lower levels are not there.

calling `configObject.framework` in code returns the object but it is of `size() == 0!`

I don't understand why the rest of the structure is not getting built.

Can any one advise why the internal structure is not being parsed and built.

Can anyone suggest what I have done wrong ?

I have just done a stripped back version like this

```
    def configText = """
    
    framework {
        environments {
            development {
                server = "local" // choice of {local|clustered}
                vertxOptions {
    
                }
    
            }
            test {
                server = "local" // choice of {local|clustered}
                vertxOptions {
    
                }
    
            }
            production {
                server = "clustered" // choice of {local|clustered}
                vertxOptions {
    
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
    """
    
    ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(configText)
    assert conf.framework?.environments?.size() == 3
```

where the error shows this

```
    Caught: Assertion failed: 
    
    assert conf.framework?.environments?.size() == 3
           |    |          |             |      |
           |    |          [:]           0      false
           |    ['environments':[:]]
           ['framework':['environments':[:]]]
    
    Assertion failed: 
    
    assert conf.framework?.environments?.size() == 3
           |    |          |             |      |
           |    |          [:]           0      false
           |    ['environments':[:]]
           ['framework':['environments':[:]]]
    
        at scripts.configSlurperTest.run(configSlurperTest.groovy:33)
        at
```

Answer (score 2):

The `environments` section when parsed by configslurper is conditional to the environment you pass to the constructor of ConfigSlurper itself.

Lets say you want the development config to be the default, but then you want to override this when run in `test` or `production`, you would do the following:

```
def configText = """

framework {

    // defaults
    
    mode = 'development'
    server = "local" // choice of {local|clustered}
    vertxOptions {

    }
    
    environments {
        // test settings
        test {
            mode = 'testing'
            
            server = "local" // choice of {local|clustered}
            vertxOptions {

            }

        }
        
        // production settings
        production {
            mode = 'live!'
            
            server = "clustered" // choice of {local|clustered}
            vertxOptions {

            }

        }
    }
}
"""

// Default values
assert new ConfigSlurper().parse(configText).framework.mode == 'development'
// Test values
assert new ConfigSlurper('test').parse(configText).framework.mode == 'testing'
// Production values
assert new ConfigSlurper('production').parse(configText).framework.mode == 'live!'
```

Comment: ok - i had not quit understood that configSlurper has special logic for an environments block.  Found this also from mrhaki https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-using-configslurper.html